# Specified cast is not valid - Decimal

Tags: c#, nullable

I'm trying to declare a decimal number which will take the value of dr["index"] or the value null if dr["index"] is null.

Here is my line of code :

```
Decimal number = (Decimal)(dr["index"] ?? 0);
```

I got the following error :

```
System.Invalid.CastException : 'Specified cast is not valid'
```

Would you know how to fix that problem ?

Comment: What type is contained in the object `dr["index"]`. What is the value?

Comment: what is the type of  `dr["index"]` ?

Comment: In particular, there's a big difference between `DBNull.Value` and null.

Comment: It's a decimal value that come from a sql server table that has been imported as a datatable in the C# program

Comment: Well, looks like its not `Decimal`. Better debugging and setting the a breakpoint to check what does it contain

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go with in case of DBNull.Value:

```
Convert.ToDecimal(dr["index"] == DBNull.Value ? 0m : dr["index"])
```

or in case of null value:

```
Convert.ToDecimal(dr["index"] ?? 0m)
```

If `dr[index]` can only be a numeric value.

Comment: `??` will not work if `dr["index"]` is null, because null in `DataTable` is `DBNull.Value`

Comment: Thank you very much , I don't have the error anymore

Comment: @edokan I edited my answer to handle DBNull.Value if that's the recieved null value

Comment: @GG24 no problem glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `Decimal.TryParse` instead:

```
Decimal d = 0;
if(Decimal.TryParse(dr["index"].ToString(), out d)) {
// Do some stuff here...
}
else {
// Connot Parse, do some other stuff...
}
```

Comment: thanks I'll try it too but the solution above from Mirko Brandt is working

Comment: it's working actually :) , (on my program at least)

Comment: @GG24 without any modifications to `dr["index"]` or casts to `string`? `dr` is `DataRow`, right?

Comment: I use it on another part of my program , so it wasn't a datarow indeed but an editautocompletion.text

Comment: That's why it works there, because you have a string. In the context of your question though, this answer isn't valid.

Comment: @John Thanks, didn´t mentioned that dr["index"] returns Object. However, by adding .ToString() that solution works